# C++ How to call the standard form of an operator from within an overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operators

I am writing some C++ code that needs to test string and character equality, and for the sake of simplicity I'd like to consider the n-dash (`0x96`) and m-dash (`0x97`) characters to be identical.

My first instinct was to redefine the equality operator, and started to code, but then ran into a problem:

```
inline bool operator==(char lhs, char rhs) {
  if (lhs == 0x96 && rhs == 0x97) return true; // works fine
  else if (lhs == 0x97 && rhs == 0x96) return true;  // works fine
  else return lhs == rhs; // infinite recursion...
}
```

In the final line of that function, ideally I'd like to be able to call 'old' form of the equality operator, similar to how a derived class is able to call a base class' version of a function.

I am wondering if this is possible in C++? If not, I'm assuming I should just extract the above code into a separate function and call the function rather than using the operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Once you overload an operator, you *replace* the default one. (There is an interesting exception: namely `std::addressof` can be used to circumvent an overloaded `&` operator).

I'd have strong reservations about overloading `operator==(char, char)`: you'll break a lot of code.

If you *really* must do it though, you could always write `(int)lhs == rhs;` which will cause conversion of *both* operators to `int` so blocking the recursion. Since `int` is a superset of `char`, this will always be defined. Oddly enough, that's why your two prior comparisons work: an implicit conversion of `char` is taking place which stops the function from calling itself.

Comment: Makes sense, so you'd recommend defining a separate function and only using that in the specific places that I need it?

Comment: Absolutely. Write your own function called `funnyEquals(char, char)`.

Comment: I don't think overloading operators for built-ins is allowed in standard C++.

Comment: Funnily enough I didn't think so either. I've never tried it but, then again, I am a scaled down version of perfection. Perhaps they have `#define char Char` and, well you can guess the rest! (Having worked in an investment bank, I've seen worse).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never attempt to overload operators purely on builtin types... Use a function instead...

Your first comparison statements worked because of [type promotion](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)

`char` will be converted to an `int` and comparisons will be made... the last one calls your operator again